# Adding new fields in pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

How can I add new fields to the schema? We are pulling in records from a SQL database and would like to add a few metadata columns in the pipeline process.

Also, is there a way to use the record duplicator plugin such that the child records have a distinct identifying field? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by metadata columns? Do they get passed on from source? While creating a pipeline you should be able to add columns in the output schema. Can you talk a little bit more about what you are trying?

Comment: No, these columns do not exist in the source. We are trying to replicate an existing Pentaho workflow. This does a source select, then adds a few new columns, some of them are simply MD5 hashes of existing identity columns, some of them are calculated datetime or amount fields. Thanks.

Comment: sacoder: One way to do would be to use wrangler transform. Wrangler allows hashing specific or encoding specific columns.